Is it possible in Python to type a function that uses the first elements of an arbitrary sized arguments list
I have a Python function that retrieves the first element of an arbitrary number of *args:
def get_first(*args):
    return tuple(a[0] for a in args)

Lets say that I call this function as follows:
b = (1, 2, 3)
c = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
x = get_first(b, c)

I expect the type Tuple[int, str]. To me it seems impossible to achieve the correct typing to accurately reveal this type.
I have had no luck with the TypeVarTuple PEP 646 or with the Paramspec PEP 612.

If you use v1, v2  = (a[0] for a in args) and then return (v1, v2) you would get the Tuple (1, 'a') you were expecting.

The signature you're looking for is related to the signature of zip; in fact, you could implement your function as next(zip(*args)).
Unfortunately, there is, at the moment, no good way to type such a function. It would require variadic generics which are not currently implemented. For example, you can see the type signature for zip here:
        @overload
        def __new__(cls, *, strict: bool = ...) -> zip[Any]: ...
        @overload
        def __new__(cls, iter1: Iterable[_T1], /, *, strict: bool = ...) -> zip[tuple[_T1]]: ...
        @overload
        def __new__(cls, iter1: Iterable[_T1], iter2: Iterable[_T2], /, *, strict: bool = ...) -> zip[tuple[_T1, _T2]]: ...
        @overload
        def __new__(
            cls, iter1: Iterable[_T1], iter2: Iterable[_T2], iter3: Iterable[_T3], /, *, strict: bool = ...
        ) -> zip[tuple[_T1, _T2, _T3]]: ...
        @overload
        def __new__(
            cls, iter1: Iterable[_T1], iter2: Iterable[_T2], iter3: Iterable[_T3], iter4: Iterable[_T4], /, *, strict: bool = ...
        ) -> zip[tuple[_T1, _T2, _T3, _T4]]: ...
        @overload
        def __new__(
            cls,
            iter1: Iterable[_T1],
            iter2: Iterable[_T2],
            iter3: Iterable[_T3],
            iter4: Iterable[_T4],
            iter5: Iterable[_T5],
            /,
            *,
            strict: bool = ...,
        ) -> zip[tuple[_T1, _T2, _T3, _T4, _T5]]: ...
        @overload
        def __new__(
            cls,
            iter1: Iterable[Any],
            iter2: Iterable[Any],
            iter3: Iterable[Any],
            iter4: Iterable[Any],
            iter5: Iterable[Any],
            iter6: Iterable[Any],
            /,
            *iterables: Iterable[Any],
            strict: bool = ...,
        ) -> zip[tuple[Any, ...]]: ...

This typechecks precisely only up to six arguments, which is good enough in practice, but is quite repetitive and rather clumsy. Unfortunately, this is probably the best you can do for now.

I’ll sadly accept your great answer :)
